# The precision of scipy.special.gammaln

Tags: python, scipy, gamma-function

### The Problem

A lot of my programming involves the statistics functions in scipy.stats. A new problem required computing the pmf of the [beta-binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) distribution. Because it has an analytic form, but doesn't show up in scipy.stats, I needed to define a function for its pmf myself. I am using scipy version 0.12.0 and numpy version 1.7.0.

```py
import numpy
from scipy.special import gammaln, betaln

def beta_binomial_pmf(k, n, K, N):
    # compute natural log of pmf
    ln_pmf = ( gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(k+1) - gammaln(n-k+1) ) + \
        - betaln(K+1,N-K+1) + betaln(K+k+1,N-K+n-k+1)
    return numpy.exp(ln_pmf)
```

In the statistics problem I am trying to solve the values of n and k normally range between 0 and 100, but K and N can be as large as 1e9. My issue is that this function will return the same value for different inputs.

### Examples

```
k = 0
n = 5
K = numpy.array([12, 10, 8])
N = 101677958
beta_binomial(k, n, L, N)
```

The resulting array is

```
array([ 0.99999928,  0.99999905,  0.99999928])
```

which is rather odd given that each of values of K is different. To get a better sense of the similarity between the first and third values in the array

```
1 - beta_binomial(k, n, L, N)
array([  7.15255482e-07,   9.53673862e-07,   7.15255482e-07])
```

---

A really simple test of the precision of the `gammaln` function is 1-(Gamma(N+1)/Gamma(N))/N. It is useful because the result is exactly 0 if you work out the algebra on paper.

```
N = numpy.logspace(0,10,11)
1-numpy.exp(gammaln(N+1)-gammaln(N))/N
array([  0.00000000e+00,  -1.11022302e-15,   1.90958360e-14,
    -9.94537785e-13,  -4.96402919e-12,   7.74684761e-11,
    -1.70086167e-13,   1.45905219e-08,   2.21033640e-07,
    -7.64616381e-07,   2.54126535e-06])
```

### Question

I recognize that there is a limit to the precision one can compute, but what happens at around N=1e7 that makes the precision change in `gammaln` by five orders of magnitude? Suggestions on how to get around this problem?

Comment: Your problem has to do with [loss of floating point precision in subtractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_precision_arithmetics#Accuracy_problems). This in fact does not depend on the precision of Scipy's gammaln and betaln. The issue is that for large `N` `gammaln(N+1)` is of the same order of magnitude as `gammaln(N)`, but much bigger than `gammaln(N+1)-gammaln(N)`. As a consequence, when you compute the difference, you lose `~ log10(gammaln(N))` digits of precision. This is a general issue with floating point.

Comment: @pv. Had a sneaking suspicion that it might be a floating point issue. Any recommendations? At some value of large N and small K switch to doing the N!/(N-K)! as N*(N-1)*(N-2)...(N-K+1)?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem has to do with [loss of floating point precision in subtractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_precision_arithmetics#Accuracy_problems). This in fact does not depend on the precision of Scipy's gammaln and betaln. The issue is that for large N, gammaln(N+1) is of the same order of magnitude as gammaln(N), but much bigger than gammaln(N+1)-gammaln(N). As a consequence, when you compute the difference, you lose ~ log10(gammaln(N)) digits of precision. This is a general issue with floating point.

You can work around this via asymtotic expansions (cf. [betaln implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cephes/beta.c#L232), which has to deal with the same issue). Namely, you can use an expansion for Gamma(a + b) - Gamma(a) for a >> |b|, 1. In Sympy:

```
In [44]: def lnstirling3(z): return (z - sympify('1/2')) * log(z) - z + log(sqrt(2*pi)) + 1/(12*z) - 1/(360*z*z*z)

In [45]: a, b = symbols('a, b')

In [46]: (lnstirling3(a + b) - lnstirling3(a)).series(a, oo, 4)

 4    3    2      3    2         2                              
b    b    b      b    b    b    b    b                          
── - ── + ──   - ── + ── - ──   ── - ─                          
12   6    12     6    4    12   2    2        ⎛1⎞    ⎛1        ⎞
──────────── + ────────────── + ────── - b⋅log⎜─⎟ + O⎜──; a → ∞⎟
      3               2           a           ⎝a⎠    ⎜ 4       ⎟
     a               a                               ⎝a        ⎠
```

Similar asymptotic formulas can be derived for your pmf in a similar way, and they can be used instead of the usual expression when the parameters have large values.

**EDIT**: if you are feeling lazy, you can use the original formula together with [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) and turn on a higher precision via `mpmath.mp.dps`. Be sure to cast k, n, K, N to `mpmath.mpf` first, before summing them, however.